# How can I find the relationship between two sides of a rectangle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]

Kabir divides a rectangle ***ABCD*** into eight non-overlapping squares as shown below. Find the ratio of ***AB*** to ***AD***.

I started with the inner most square and called that side $a_1$. Then the sides of the second biggest square I called $a_2$. Then

$a_1+a_2=a_3$

$a_1+a_3=a_4$

$a_1+a_4=a+5$

What can I do now?

Comment: The picture above is just a rotated view of what you are used to. The vertical axis is in the variable $x$ and the horizontal axis is in the variable $y$

Comment: A parabola is a parabola, no matter how it is oriented. Writing $y$ as a quadratic in $x$ gives a parabola opening up or down. Writing $x$ as a quadratic in $y$ gives a parabola opening to the left or right. Certain equations involving $x^2, y^2$ and $xy$ terms give parabolas that are slanted. It is the shape that makes it a parabola, not the orientation.

Comment: Instead of replacing your parabola question, you should have posted the rectangle question separately. (They're free!) Since no one answered the parabola question in over three months, I suppose there's no harm done (although the comments above now make no sense); likewise, since someone has already answered the rectangle question, I won't suggest rolling the question back to the previous form. In the future, please be mindful that someone *could* be working on an answer to a question, even months later, so that self-vandalizing a question this way may turn their effort into a waste of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set the side of smallest square as $a$, and second smallest square as $b$, you will complete the length of side of all square:

[image]

To find that $a+2b = 8a-2b$ and so $4b = 7a$. This concludes 
$$AB:AD=(5a+2b):(7a+b)=34:35$$